# On solving the differential equation $y''=y'+y+x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Now at some point, you might have come across the differential equation$$y'=y+x$$which has the easily verifiable solution$$y(x)=ce^x-x-1$$however, I wanted to try solving$$y''=y'+y+x$$which while it would be more difficult, I thought that I might be able to solve it. Here is my attempt at doing so:

This differential equation looked like the general solution might be a sum of the complementary solution and the particular solution. To find the complementary solution, we need to solve$$y''-y'-y=0$$This is how this is done:

1. Assume that a solution will be proportional to $e^{\lambda x}$ for some $\lambda$. Substituting that in gets us$$\lambda^2e^{\lambda x}-\lambda e^{\lambda x}-e^{\lambda x}=0$$and dividing all terms by $e^{\lambda x}$ gets us$$\lambda^2-\lambda-1=0$$

Wait a second. This looks familiar. The solution to this quadratic is$$\lambda=\phi,\overline\phi$$where $\overline\phi$ represents the conjugate of the golden ratio $\phi$. So the complementary function is$$y(x)=c_1e^{\phi x}+c_2e^{\overline\phi x}$$Now to find the particular solution to the diff. eq., which is where I'm currently stuck, as I do not know how to do so. So my question is:

#### How do I solve the diff. eq. $y''=y'+y+x$?

Comment: Are you familiar with https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx

Comment: @Moo No not really

Comment: **Hint:** Find the complementary solution of $y'' - y' - y = 0$ and then the particular solution using the guess for $y_p(x) = a + b x$. There are other approaches too.

Comment: Assume there is some highest term $cx^2$ , then $y`$ is linear & $y``$ is Constant , hence there is nothing to "balance" or "cancel" the $cx^2$ term. Similarly when we take higher Powers. Hence , we must have linear function $y=ax+b$ , which will then work out to $y=-x+1$ here !

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? Despite my lack of knowledge, this seems like a perfectly valid question, and OP has met all criteria.

Comment: According to my earlier comment , the Solution should be "your Complimentary function + my Particular Solution" , where I got like $-x+1$ , which can be easily verified. The accepted answer currently has $1-x$ which is clearly wrong & should be rectified.

Comment: @Prem $1-x$ and $-x+1$ are exactly the same thing. It doesn't need to be rectified.

Comment: @zxen-xi I think it's because I didn't try to attempt the particular solution, making it a "no clue" question in that sense, although that's just my guess.

Comment: There was a typo in my comment : I got $(-x+1)$ while the accepted answer has $(+x-1)$ , which is negative of that , @CrSb0001 , hence that has to be rectified.

Comment: @Prem Oh my bad

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f''(x)=f'(x)+f+x$. The let $g''(x)-g'(x)-g=0, $ i.e. g is a solution to the corresponding homogenous equation..

We can often find a $\lambda(x)$ so that $f=\lambda g$

$f=\lambda g$

$f'=\lambda ' g + \lambda g'$

$f''=\lambda'' g + 2\lambda' g' + \lambda g''$

$f''-f'-f=\lambda'' g + 2\lambda' g' + \lambda g'' - (\lambda ' g + \lambda g') - \lambda g=\lambda(g''-g'-g)+\lambda '(2g'-g)+\lambda''g=x$

Now let $u=\lambda '$.

Then $(2g'-g)u+u'g=x$

$g$ is known and the new equation is first order in $u$. Thus the technique is called Reduction of Order.

This works for any solution for $g$ so you only need one of the two $Ce^{kx}$. So we can let $g=Ce^{kx}$

$u'Ce^{kx}+u(2k-1)Ce^{kx}=x\implies u'+u(2k-1)=(x/C)e^{-kx}$

Now you can introuce an integrating factor $\mu(x)=e^{(2k-1)x}$

$\frac{d}{dx}(ue^{(2k-1)x})=(x/C)e^{(k-1)x}\implies u=e^{-(2k-1)x}\int (x/C) e^{(k-1)x}dx$

$\lambda = \int u dx$ and $f=\lambda g$

This is more complicated than the method of Undetermined Coefficients.

$y''=y'+y+x \implies y = g(x)+p(x)$ where $p(x)=ax+b$.

We have $p''=0$ and $0=p'+p+x=a+ax+b+x=(a+1)x+(a+b)$. We let $a=-1$ and $a+b=0\implies b=1$

So $y=c_1e^{\phi x}+c_2e^{\bar{\phi} x}-x+1$

While simpler, Reduction of Order is more general and a variation can be used to simplify an equation. For example $y''+(mx^2+b)y=0$ can be reduced to an equation of the form $ag''+bg'+cg=0$ where $a,b$ and $c$ are linear functions of $x$ and $y=\lambda(x) g(x)$ and $\lambda'' +mx^2\lambda =0$. In other words, a function is determined with the same asymptotic behavior then the solution is expressed as a multiple of this function. This can simplify the equation and make other methods more convenient, like Taylor Series substitution by lowering the exponent of the first non-zero coefficient.

These  methods can essentially be combined via [The Method of Frobenius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method).

Comment: According to my comments to OP , the Solution should involve $-x+1$ , which can be easily verified. This answer currently has $1-x$ which is clearly wrong. It should be rectified for correctness !

Comment: A typo in my comment : According to my comments to OP , the Solution should involve $(−x+1)$ , which can be easily verified. This answer currently has $(+x-1)$ , which is negative of that. That is wrong & should be rectified for correctness !!

Comment: Thanks. Fixed! Had Left out a term.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** We can use [*Undetermined Coefficients*](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/undeterminedcoefficients.aspx).

Find the complementary solution, $y_c(x)$ of $y'' - y' - y = 0$.

Then, find the particular solution using the guess for $y_p(x) = a + b x$.

The solution will be $$y(x) = y_c(x) + y_p(x)$$

There are other approaches too (Variation of Parameters, Laplace Transform...).